# KineticJS: is there any way of getting the height of a Sprite?

Tags: height, width, sprite, kineticjs, dimensions

So KineticJS supports sprites, and I am using sprites in my current project. Is there any way I can get the height of a sprite object?

Because you can get the height of every single object in KineticJS like this:

object.getHeight();

That also applies for getting the width.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

getHeight() return 0 for Spline.

You can define your getHeight and getWidth functions:

```
Kinetic.Spline.prototype.getWidth = function(){
  var points = this.getPoints();
  var minX = points[0].x;
  var maxX = points[0].x;
  for(var i = 1; i < points.length;i++){
    if(points[i].x < minX){
        minX = points[i].x;
    }
    if(points[i].x > maxX){
        maxX = points[i].x;
    }
  }
  return maxX - minX;
}

Kinetic.Spline.prototype.getHeight = function(){
  var points = this.getPoints();
  var minY = points[0].y;
  var maxY = points[0].y;
  for(var i = 1; i < points.length;i++){
    if(points[i].y < minY){
        minY = points[i].y;
    }
    if(points[i].y > maxY){
        maxY = points[i].y;
    }
  }
  return maxY - minY;
}
```

But this is approximation of real height/width.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/EM35c/

Answer (score 0):

Lavtron's answer refers to **Spline**, not **Sprite**  (similar looking words for entirely different things!).  Good news, for **Sprite** you *can* use:

**spriteObj.getHeight()** and **spriteObj.getWidth()** for sprites, just as you do for everything else.

*However* I have found that you must ensure that **height** and **width** properties are first specified explicitly in the declaration of your sprite object when you initialize it. Otherwise these methods return 'undefined' when later called.  It won't automatically measure the height and return it with getHeight(), you must ensure it is specified in the Sprite object as a value (eg. 32) in order for getHeight() to return that value.